# Struts-jquery - Ajax call data from server to datatable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have popup window with submit button.It should not go to another page or close, so I need ajax submit. I'm using struts2-jquery-plugin for tag. But its forwarding to another page.
How to get the array of data from action class in single button click ?

This popup page button need to interact the action class to get the data and display in datatable.

I have `JSONArray` data in action , but I need to configure those to aaData: in datatable.How to get the data in datatable ?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
 <head>
<sj:head/>
</head>
<body>
 <sj:dialog autoOpen="false" id="popup" modal="true" height="500"  width="700">
 <s:form id="form" action="">
  <input type="textbox" name="data">   
  <sj:submit value="submit form" targets="result" ></sj:submit>
 </s:form>
 </sj:dialog>
 <sj:a href="#" openDialog="popup" >Open Dialog</sj:a>
</body>
```

Please advise...

Comment: If it is a popup window, then it will go in *another* window: the popup one...  Post more details: struts.xml, relevant part of the action, and try to be the clearer you can. Please note that a popup is most of the time the bad design choice :/

Comment: Thanks for reply. As like above program open dialog when click link.In dialog box has form and submit button. I need to get the jsonarray values from action class when click <sj:buton> in dialogbox. Once get the jsonarray values to pass to datatable aaData.